# Apple iPad 10W USB Power Adapter

Tags: charger

can you tell me what are the specifications of Apple iPad 10W USB Power Adapter i.e. power input,output,volt.ampher,etc

Comment: It's in small grey-on-white print on the charger.  Some say 2.1A, 5.1V. There are multiple slightly different models, e.g. A1357 says this.

Answer (score 2):

Input

- Voltage 100V-240V AC
- Frequency: 50/60Hz
- Wattage: 0.45A

Output

- Voltage : 5V DC
- Current: up to 2A
- Wattage: up to 10W